# PDF e-sign. How a signature tight with a person who signs legally?

Tags: pdf

I know how signature works, etc. Maybe it's not about pdf but about e-sign, but whatever.
Imagine we have a contract "I give you $100, you give me a cookie" (expensive cookie). Imagine you and me generated private|public keys signed that contract.
Then I gave you $100 but you didn't give me the cookie. I want to go to a сourt, but you removed your private key and tell me that you never signed anything. How court knows that YOU signed that document if anyone can generate sign keys. They are not tight in any way with a signer. Government doesn't have any record like "this public key id a public key of that person ID" to demand from you to give me my cookie. How that works legally? If we both say "yes, we signed" - it's easy, but we can easy say - I don't sign that and nobody can 100% prove that I used that key to sign.

Comment: This is a legal question, not a programming question.

Comment: Well, alternatively this question asks for explanation of PKIs etc. Which also is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not use self signed certificates, you use certificates issued by a trusted certificate authority (CA). Then when you sign the contract you include long term validation (LTV) data in your signature so that it can be validated even if the certificate has been revoked.

Comment: Is [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) a trusted certificate authority? Can I sign a PDF with it?

Comment: @Akxe OpenSSL is not a certificate authority. You can generate self signed certificates with OpenSSL.

Comment: Well... letsencrypt is, is that a valid solution?

Comment: Do they offer document signing certificates?

Comment: After reading through, it seems not. Also as I read more, I think there will never be any CA that does PDF signing, there are licence fees required to be paid by CA...